# Encoding binary data using string class

Tags: c++

I am going through one of the requirment for string implementations as part of study project.

> Let us assume that the standard library did not exist and we were
>   foced to design our own string class. What functionality  would it
>   support and what limitations would we improve. Let us consider
>   following factors.
>
> 1. Does binary data need to be encoded?
> 2. Is multi-byte character encoding acceptable or is unicode necessary?
> 3. Can C-style functions be used to provide some of the needed functionality?
> 4. What kind of insertion and extraction operations are required?

My question on above text

1. What does author mean by "Does binary data need to be encoded?". Request to explain with example and how can we implement this.
2. What does author mean y point 2. Request to explain with example and how can we implement this.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I think #1 is asking, "Does a string need to be able to store arbitrary binary data?".  This would be in contrast to a regular C-style string, where you couldn't store data that contained zero-valued bytes, since a zero-valued character is used to represent the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

1. The question here is "can we store ANY old data in the string, or does certain byte-values need to be encoded in some special way. An example of that would be in the standard C language, if you want to use a newline character, it is "encoded" as `\n` to make it more readable and clear - of course, in this example I'm talking of in the source code. In the case of binary data stored in the string, how would you deal with "strange" data - e.g. what about zero bytes? Will they need special treatment?
2. The values guaranteed to fit in a `char` is ASCII characters and a few others (a total of 256 different characters in a typical implementation, but `char` is not GUARANTEED to be 8 bits by the standard). But if we take non-european languages, such as Chinese or Japanese, they consist of a vastly higher number than the ones available to fit in a single `char`. Unicode allows for several million different characters, so any character from any european, chinese, japanese, thai, arabic, mayan, and ancient hieroglyphic language can be represented in one "unit". This is done by using a wider character - for the full size, we need 32 bits. The drawback here is that most of the time, we don't actually use that many different characters, so it is a bit wasteful to use 32 bits for each character, only to have zero's in the upper 24 bits nearly all the time.

A multibyte character encoding is a compromise, where "common" characters (common in the European languages) are used as one `char`, but less common characters are encoded with multiple `char` values, using a special range of character to indicate "there is more data in the next `char` to combine into a single unit". (Or,one could decide to use 2, 3, or 4 `char` each time, to encode a single character).

Comment: What do you mean by binary data stored in string?

Comment: Your explanation is primarily correct, but there's at least one subtle issue that could cause confusion: it's not "multibyte character set" but "multibyte encoding", and just means that multiple bytes can be used to represent characters but doesn't specify whether the number of bytes used to represent the characters is fixed or variable.

Comment: Thus, all the various Unicode encodings are multibyte, with UTF-8 being the usual variable-length one (and having the special feature that it's not just "common" characters stored in one byte but the ASCII character encoding, which specifies 128 characters [not all printable] stored in 7 bits and thus allows interoperability with ASCII data).

Comment: @venkysmarty: Binary data - something that isn't text. Using a "string" to store, for example, machine code generated by the compiler, or using string as a storage for a multiprecision math library, storing the binary representation of a 6000 decimal places of `pi`, or some such.

Comment: @JAB: I have reworded the two last paragraphs a little bit, hopefully that makes is a little clearer. I don't want to give the OP the idea that there is only one solution to this problem, tho'.

Comment: @venkysmarty That's a consequence of the fact that C strings are just `char` arrays (or pointers to `char`) containing a null byte; a C compiler can't know if a character array is really a string or if it just holds a list of 1-byte integers that happens to have at least one zero-filled byte in it. It's up to the programmer to make sure that strings are properly handled as strings and raw character arrays are not.

Comment: @JAB: "multibyte encoding" is usually considered a synonym for "variable-length encoding". For example, [IBM's compiler docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Fstandlib%2Fref%2Fmbchar.htm): “multibyte characters (sequences of one or more bytes)” and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey142t48(v=vs.80).aspx) says that DBCS characters (a special case of multibyte characters) can be either one or two bytes wide. Fixed-width encodings that use more than one byte are commonly referred to as wide-character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding point one, "Binary data" refers to sequences of bytes, where "bytes" almost always means eight-bit words. In the olden days, most systems were based on ASCII, which requires seven bits (or eight, depending on who you ask). There was, therefore, no need to distinguish between bytes and characters. These days, we're more friendly to non-English speakers, and so we have to deal with Unicode (among other codesets). This raises the problem that string types need to deal with the fact that bytes and characters are no longer the same thing.

This segues onto point two, which is about how you represent strings of characters in a program. UTF-8 uses a variable-length encoding, which has the remarkable property that it encodes the entire ASCII character set using exactly the same bytes that ASCII encoding uses. However, it makes it more difficult to, e.g., count the number of characters in a string. For pure ASCII, the answer is simple: characters = bytes. But if your string might have non-ASCII characters, you now have to walk the string, decoding characters, in order to find out how many there are<sup>1</sup>.

These are the kinds of issues you need to think about when designing your string class.

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't as difficult as it might seem, since the first byte of each character is guaranteed not to have 10 in its two high-bits. So you can simply count the bytes that satisfy `(c & 0xc0) != 0xc0`. Nonetheless, it is still expensive relative to just treating the length of a string buffer as its character-count.

Comment: why first byte character is guarnateed not to have 10 in its two high bits. Can you please eloborate? Thanks

Comment: @venkysmarty: UTF-8 is defined that way. Look it up on Wikipedia.